# Select option onclick function works in FF but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can successfully change the chart option in firefox, but it doesn't work in chrome (no errors). I have read almost all of the topics about this issue, but none of them worked for me. What is the correct way to catch when user selects options ?

[image]

```
<select id="sortby2">
  <option id="byweek" value="date">7 days</option>
  <option id="by14" value="spent">14 days</option>
  <option id="bymonth" value="clicks">30 days</option>
</select>

$("#by14").OnClick(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "chartdata.php",
    data: 'by14=on',datatype:"html",  async: false,
    success: function(d){
    $('.cantent').html(d);      
    }       
});
});
```

Comment: Use onchange function

Comment: `$("#by14").change(function(){`

Comment: for select option changes, in jQuery you can use [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use [**change()**](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of `click` event.

```
$("#sortby2").change(function(){

  if($(this).find('option:selected')[0].id != 'by14')
           return;

  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "chartdata.php",
        data: 'by14=on',datatype:"html",  async: false,
        success: function(d){
        $('.cantent').html(d);      
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok but it should work with select id only. How can I listen if someone changes options ? I edited my question with my select code also.

Comment: You have to give id of select not option, you need to bind the change to select by id sortby2, check my updated answer

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this runs whatever user select ? I only want to run this when user clicks by14 option.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for a "change" event on the select element. It's best to use the jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to register it:

```
$("#sortby2").on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'spent') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "chartdata.php",
            data: 'by14=on',datatype:"html",  async: false,
            success: function(d){
                $('.cantent').html(d);      
            }       
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok but it should work with select id only. How can I listen if someone changes options ? I edited my question with my select code also.

Comment: Ah, you should attach the listener to the select element rather than the option. I updated the code in my answer to reflect that...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this runs whatever user select option ? I only want to run this when user clicks by14 option.

Comment: I updated so my answer so that the ajax call is only fired if they select the by14 option. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Just curiosity, why you used 3 "=" instead of 1 ?

Comment: @user198989 Single = assigns a value to a variable, == does a comparison for equality by value, === does a comparison for equality on both value and type. For example, "1" == 1 is true, because the values are both 1, however "1" === 1 is false because while both values are 1, the first is a string the second is a number. x = 1 means that the variable x now has a value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#by14").click` not `$("#by14").onclick`